# Circular dependency: Magento\Customer\Model\Session depends on Magento\Customer\Model\Url and vice versa

Tags: magento2, error, dependency

Magento2 shows this error:

```
Circular dependency: Magento\Customer\Model\Session depends on Magento\Customer\Model\Url and vice versa.
```

I have cleared `var/cache` and `var/generation` directory. But it doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not happen.
Make sure you have this in the `di.xml` of the customer module

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Session">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configShare" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="customerUrl" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Url\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="customerResource" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
        <argument name="customerRepository" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

this means that the session model would use as dependency `Magento\Customer\Model\Url\Proxy` instead of `Magento\Customer\Model\Url`.

Clear the `var/generation` folder in case something was wrongly generated.

Comment: above xml content is already available in customer module, what to do next for my case, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220744/circular-dependency-magento-customer-model-session-depends-on-company-modulenam/220787?noredirect=1#comment306478_220787

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I have no other idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you use redis for caching, I just ran a redis-cli FLUSHALL and it fixed after that.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue about is back on GitHub a while ago: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/762

Try to run the following to clear your cache and generation folders:

```
rm -Rf /path/to/magento2/var/cache/*
rm -Rf /path/to/magento2/var/generation/*
```

Comment: thanks.. but i have already checked this issue on GitHub. it not helped me to solve my problem