# Circular dependency: Magento\Customer\Model\Session depends on Company\Modulename\Plugin\Config\Share and vice versa

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

How to override or Use plugin for **`isWebsiteScope()`** function from 
**Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share.php** file,

**I have used plugin for below function but I want to get current customer session in below function, Mainly check custoemr is logged in or not**.

Just use plugin and set di.xml,

```
<!-- Override Share.php to set value of website scope -->
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share">
    <plugin name="Company_Modulename::Share" type="\Company\Modulename\Plugin\Config\Share\Proxy" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

In Share.php file,

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Plugin\Config;

class Share
{    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
    }
    /**
     * Check whether current customers sharing scope is website
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterIsWebsiteScope(\Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share $subject)
    {
        if(!$this->session->isLoggedIn()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

How to get current customer session in above function,

**If I used current customer session using customer session model browser will throw Circular dependacy error.**

Comment: Where can be duplicate this issue frontend or admin ?

Comment: You cannot get the customer session using the above pattern because `Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share` is a dependency of `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`, hence the circular dependency error -- I see what you are trying to do (i.e. change the website scope if the customer is logged in) but couldn't figure out a non-hacky way either.

Comment: @zedBlackbeard, For frontend.

Comment: @PhilBirnie, Any Hacky way to resolve issue of get current customer session?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya , Lastly I used object Manager to solve this issue, Even I am open for better answer

Comment: Yes as @MurtuzaZabuawala You need to use object manager for this issue. But use object manager as dependency `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface`

Comment: hi @RakeshJesadiya Did you get the solution for this? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to resolve circular dependencies (though not always the best) is to use Proxies.

Proxy for a class is an auto-generated class (meaning, Magento will create it automatically if not found through auto-loader) which has a dependency on the Object Manager and has the same interface as the original class.

Implementation of any method of the Proxy is just an invocation of the same method of the original class. It does not have original class required in constructor, instead the object of the original class is created through the Object Manager the first time some method of the Proxy is invoked.

Here is an example of the Proxy from the core (`\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Proxy`):

```
/**
 * Get proxied instance
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth
 */
protected function _getSubject()
{
    if (!$this->_subject) {
        $this->_subject = true === $this->_isShared
            ? $this->_objectManager->get($this->_instanceName)
            : $this->_objectManager->create($this->_instanceName);
    }
    return $this->_subject;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setAuthStorage($storage)
{
    return $this->_getSubject()->setAuthStorage($storage);
}
```

To use a proxy, instead of reference to the class (anywhere in di.xml or in constructor dependency), reference the Proxy by appending the name of the class with `\Proxy`, i.e.:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share">
<plugin name="Company_Modulename::Share" type="\Company\Modulename\Plugin\Config\Share\Proxy" sortOrder="1"/>
```

It is always worthwhile analyzing are there ways to rewrite the business logic to avoid circular dependencies before using Proxies (or for the same matter an Object Manager in constructor)

Comment: How to get customer session in proxy.php file using above way? Still same error coming

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya just keep the plugin the way you wrote it, but change di.xml and specify the plugin type with the `\Proxy` suffix (as in my example above). Do not create the Proxy class manually.

Comment: Given same error again using above way. Circular dependency: Magento\Customer\Model\Session depends on Company\Modulename\Plugin\Config\Share and vice versa.

Comment: I have updated my questions based on your comment but not working

Comment: I see, the problem is that the method `isWebsiteScope ` is invoked from the constructor of the `Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Storage`, that's why even though we used Proxy, object still need to be created at the construction time. I don't see how Object Manager helps your either (doesn't work for me). I wold rather look more deeply at what business logic you want to implement and add it on a different level.

Comment: So we cant get any resolutions for above issue, I need to get only customer session in Share.php file

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this plugin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75449/discussion-between-rakesh-jesadiya-and-eugene-tulika).

Answer (score 1):

The only way That I found to remove circular dependency is to use `objectManager` directly ,

I know that is ugly way to solve , but I think this is the only way,

If some one has better solution Then I am also open for solution

But my way below is the solution :

```
protected $_objectManager;

public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
)
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
}

public function afterIsWebsiteScope(\Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share $subject)
{
    $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I also think that this is the only way to solve `circular dependency` but we should use object manager as a dependency in class files. +1 from me :)

Comment: Its not working yet and show same error.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya did you remove `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` from constructor ?? and delete var/generation

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. remove generated and var folder from root

Comment: now error is look like,Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /var/www/html/studentkare/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya please try with `$this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');`

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya please check updated answer

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Same Error again.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya may be your customer session is not created yet that's why you get this error